# what is a project in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, project

I've just started working with Eclipse for C++ and I just want to clarify something that I haven't been able to figure out by searching so far.  Is a project folder in eclipse only intended to have one program in it?  i.e., a what is meant by project is basically a C++ program?  And so you're not supposed to store many different programs in one project directory?  Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, though they are trying to change that:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/towards-more-flexible-projects.html

> Eclipse requires that the contents of each project be stored in a
>   single directory on disk. Every file and folder in that directory tree
>   on disk must belong to the project in the workspace

Comment: Say I want to write a bunch of very small but independent, unrelated programs (like 4-6 lines each).  Do I have to create a whole new project for each of these?  It just seems like a very inconvenient process if all I'm doing writing small programs.

Comment: yep, it is a bit inconvenient ... but as they say in france, ce la vie!

Answer (score 0):

Project is a project. You could divine you aplication to .dll, .exe, or other stuffs. When you are developing something that could go apart in another solution the you can put apart that piece (.dll for example). When you are developing in Visual Studio you can see that projects are in final a single file that has some own functionality, and the whole program is called solution. Didn't fired up Eclipse for a while, but it goes in the same direction. I can remember that projects in Eclipse were very poor, and meaning of the project was considered with actual language that you use (Java, C/C++, PHP, PYTHON, etc.).
Good definition is that project hold some part of application (if not all of it).